# Not getting background image for TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to add a background image to the table view. My code for this is here:

```
UIImageView *backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[backImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
[self.view addSubview:backImageView];

UITableView *aTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[aTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];

[aTableView setDelegate:self];
[aTableView setDataSource:self];
[aTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:aTableView];
[aTableView release];
```

I am not getting a background image, and I don't want to use AppDelegate. Anybody help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is already answered in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898351/iphone-setting-background-on-uitableview). The solution in the referenced question is less code than you are using here.

Answer (score 0):

@sny i suggest you to try this .....give the imageview to the background of the view

In -

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`  //this will clear you views background

```
UIImageView *Image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:Image];
        [Image release];
```

//Now you have the image in the background of the view

`[self.view insertSubview:Image atIndex:0];` //this will set imageviews index to zero

```
}
```

Now you will always get the image in the background of your `TableView`
But also make sure that you had clear the backgroung of your `TableView`

//Now write code for your table view as u had written above in your class

I Hope this will help you .....Good Luck!!!