# Giving Backgroundimage of Tableview custom origin

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to give a tableview a custom origin/size? Adding a Backgroundimage to a Tableview is explained here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898351/iphone-setting-background-on-uitableviewcontroller). But can i tell in viewdidload the position of it?

I thought about something like:

```
mytableView.backgroundView?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
```

or

```
mytableView.backgroundView?.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
```

implementing in viewDidLoad(). But it just fills the whole UIScreen and doesn't react on the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: r u try to set the background image for table view or try to change the frame of tableview

Comment: but your coding is fine , if you are used in the auto layout change the constraint

Comment: The frame of tableview is fine. But i want to change the frame of the background image of tableview. By the way, I just try to add some constraints and it looks like it changes its position. But i thought actually that the code above should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a one custom `UIView` which has clear background color `UITableView` inside of it. Then you can add `UIImageView`back of this `UITableView`. You'd know the `tableView`'s frame and resize your `imageView`'s frame and origin whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution:

- Set background image view to UIView.
- Add UITableView on that UIView.
- Set UITableView background color as clear color.
- Now you can reset any position either of UITableView or background UIImageView. It will work fine.